# Prove $\gcd(a+b,a^2+b^2)$ is $1$ or $2$ if $\gcd(a,b) = 1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

> Assuming that $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, prove that $\gcd(a+b,a^2+b^2) = 1$ or $2$.

I tried this problem and ended up with
$$d\mid 2a^2,\quad d\mid 2b^2$$
where $d = \gcd(a+b,a^2+b^2)$, but then I am stuck; by these two conclusions how can I conclude $d=1$ or $2$? 
And also is there any other way of proving this result?

Comment: Hint: you can consider $d|2ab$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From what you have found, you can conclude easily.

If $d$ divides two numbers, it also divides their gcd, so

$$d| \gcd (2a^2,2b^2) = 2 \gcd (a,b) ^2 =2.$$

So, $d$ is a divisor of 2 and thus either 1 or 2.

---

Answer (score 7):

Suppose that the $\operatorname{gcd}\:(a+b,a^{2}+b^{2})= d$. Then we have the following:

- $d\mid (a+b)$ and $d \mid (a^{2}+b^{2})$
- Now $a^{2}+b^{2} = (a+b)^{2} - 2ab  \Rightarrow d \mid 2\cdot a \cdot b$.
- Now since $d\mid (2 \cdot a \cdot b)$ either $d =1,2$ or $d\mid a$ or $d \mid b$.
- Now if $d\mid a \Rightarrow$  $d \mid b$ since $d \mid (a+b)$. So $d\nmid a$ and $d \nmid b$.

Comment: I didn't understood the last point if d|a it implies d|b that correct but then how you had concluded d doesn't divide a and b.

Comment: @SaurabhHota: if $d \mid a$ along with $d \mid (a+b)$ gives $d \mid b$ which contradicts $(a,b)=1$. Apply same argument of what will happen if $d \mid b$

Comment: $d$ being a  common divisor of $a$ and $b$ does not contradict the fact that $(a,b) = 1$. If this were the case, then $d \mid (a,b)$, since any common divisor of two integers must also be a divisor of the gcd of those two integers,  hence $d \mid 1$. It follows then, that $d = 1$, since $1$ is the only positive divisor of $1$.

Answer (score 4):

Since $\text{gcd}(a,b) = 1$, we have that there exists $x,y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $$ax+by = 1$$ Hence, we have that $$(a+b)x + b(y-x) = 1$$ and $$a(x-y) + (a+b)y = 1$$
Squaring and adding the two equations, we get that $$(a+b)^2 x^2 + b^2(y-x)^2 + 2b(a+b)x(y-x) + (a+b)^2 y^2 + a^2(x-y)^2 + 2a(a+b)y(x-y) = 2$$
Rearranging the above equation, we get that
$$(a+b) \left( (a+b) (x^2+y^2) + 2 (x-y) (ay-bx) \right) + (a^2 + b^2)(x-y)^2 = 2$$
Hence, we have that $$(a+b) X + (a^2 + b^2) Y =2$$
where $X = \left( (a+b) (x^2+y^2) + 2 (x-y) (ay-bx) \right)$ and $Y = (x-y)^2$. This implies that $\text{gcd}(a,b) \vert 2$.

Hence, $$\text{gcd}(a,b) = 1 \text{ or } 2$$

Answer (score 1):

If $d$ divides $a+b$ then it divides $a(a+b)=a^2+ab$ so if it also divides $a^2+b^2$ then it divides $a^2+ab-(a^2+b^2)=ab-b^2=b(a-b)$. A similar calculation shows it divides $a(a-b)$. Then from $\gcd(a,b)=1$ we get $d$ divides $a-b$. But then it divides $(a+b)+(a-b)=2a$ and $(a+b)-(a-b)=2b$, so it's 1 or 2.